# If $f(x)≤x$ , then $f′(x)≤1$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm studying Calculus and having a trouble solving this question.

1) If $f(x)\leq x$, then $f′(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$?

2) What if $f(0)=0$, $f′(x)$ exists for all $x$?

I could easily find the counter example for 1) (Therefore it is false)

But I'm not sure about 2)

If $f(0)=0$ and $f′(x)$ exists for all $x$  &
$f(x)\leq x$ , then $f′(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$?

Please leave a comment if you don't mind :)

Comment: The question is unclear: is the exercise
``consider a differentiable function $f$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)\leq x$ for all $x$. Show that $f'(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$.''?

Comment: I'm not sure that the new edits improved the question. I preferred the original version of the question, which gave a little more context.

Comment: Don't remove relevant information from your question!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Consider $$f(x)=x-A \sin^2 x $$
for large $A$.

Answer (score 4):

Draw the line $y=x$, and then draw any kind of squiggly function you want that stays below or touches the line. In particular, the function $f(x)=x-e^{-x}$ has $f'(x)\gt1$ for *all* $x$, while $f(x)=x-{1\over2}x^2$ satisfies $f(0)=0$ but $f'(x)\gt1$ for $x\lt0$.

Remark: The original version of the OP's question had two parts, with the condition $f(0)=0$ being added in the second part. The function $f(x)=x-e^{-x}$, of course, does not satisfy that condition.

Answer (score -2):

Let for example $f(x)=x\sin x$, then $f(0)=0$ and for any real $x$ $f(x)\leq x$. Then the derivative will look like this: $f'(x)=\sin x+x\cos x$ and so will exist for all $x$. Taking $x=2\pi n$, where $n$ is positive integer we get $f'(x)=2\pi n$, which evidently has no upper limitation.

Comment: $f(x)\leq x$ fails for $x$ negative.